# Removing text between "|" delimiter and "," delimiter using shell script

Tags: regex, unix, sh, ksh

I have a large multi-lined file that is being pulled from a database the file has fields delimited by commas and if the field has multiple values the values are separated by "|"

#### example input:

> name,title,email1|email2|email3,phone,address

In a shell script I need to remove "|email2|email3"

#### example output:

> name,title,email1,phone,address

I need to do this for each line in the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `sed`:

```
sed "s/\|[^,]*//g"
```

Result:

```
h2co3-macbook:~ h2co3$ echo "name,title,email1|email2|email3,phone,address" | sed "s/\|[^,]*//g"
name,title,email1,phone,address
h2co3-macbook:~ h2co3$
```

Comment: I believe you don't even need to escape "|" in that exemple

Answer (score 1):

Using sed:

```
sed -i 's/|[^,]*//g' filename
```

Note that in most regex flavors `|` is a special character that specifies alternation, and to match a literal `|` you need to use `\|`.  This is not the case for sed, to match a literal `|` you use `|` and for alternation you use `\|` (unless an extended regex option is specified).

Answer (score 1):

Use sed with inline option:

```
sed -i.bak 's/|[^|,]*//g' inFile
```

#### Live Demo: http://ideone.com/zKUVhl

Answer (score 0):

This answer splits the input into fields and outputs the ones you want.

```
awk -F'[|,]' -v OFS=, '{print $1, $2, $3, $(NF-1), $NF}' file
```